# Dependency issue with React Native

Tags: react-native, npm

I am having an issue installing a react-native project. This is a project from about a year ago that I'm trying to update with latest React. However, I am having a dependency issue.

I think this is an issue with `react-native-scalable-image`. However, if I do a:

`npm install --save react-native-scalable-image --legacy-peer-deps`

it looks like it works, but then if I try to install something else such as:

`npm install --save react-native-screens`

I get the following:

```
MacBook-Pro-3:project johnny$ npm install --save react-native-screens
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-scalable-image@1.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16" from @react-native-masked-view/masked-view@0.2.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-masked-view/masked-view
npm ERR!     @react-native-masked-view/masked-view@"^0.2.9" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @react-navigation/core@6.4.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/core
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/core@"^6.4.9" from @react-navigation/native@6.1.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm ERR!       peer @react-navigation/native@"^6.0.0" from @react-navigation/elements@1.3.18
npm ERR!       node_modules/@react-navigation/elements
npm ERR!         @react-navigation/elements@"^1.3.18" from @react-navigation/stack@6.3.17
npm ERR!         node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm ERR!       2 more (@react-navigation/stack, the root project)
npm ERR!   16 more (@react-navigation/elements, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.3" from react-native-scalable-image@1.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-scalable-image
npm ERR!   react-native-scalable-image@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.3" from react-native-scalable-image@1.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-scalable-image
npm ERR!     react-native-scalable-image@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/johnny/.npm/_logs/2023-09-21T01_55_14_959Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/johnny/.npm/_logs/2023-09-21T01_55_14_959Z-debug-0.log
```

Is the problem with react-native-scalable-image, or is it with something else? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Hi @kojow, 
You can use yarn inspect of using npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-native-scalable-image wants an older version of react to be present. This narrow version lockdown might be too strict, so you could try to add this override to package.json:

```
"overrides": {
  "react-native-scalable-image": {
    "react": "18.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. Will give that a try. Do you know why `--legacy-peer-deps` was not working for this?